# Create a new known_hosts file for openSSH in windows

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh, known-hosts

So i have OpenSSH in windows 7 at a university and i am basicly having this problem:

When i first use SSH it is trying to create the known_hosts file on my university network drive H:

[image]

But this is not what i want. How can i define a knew location for the known_hosts file and get it to generate there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the environment variable `HOME` to a directory in which you want the `.ssh` directory to be stored.

Comment: How do i set and check HOME?

Comment: and are you sure the environment variable is home because %HOME% is not recognised.

Comment: See http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html.  What do you mean by "%HOME% is not recognized"?

Comment: i cant cd to %HOME% it says that it is not a recognised path.

Comment: Does `echo %HOME%` show you the value of the variable?  If so, the variable is set.  Get that working, and the rest should work too.

Answer (score 0):

use variable name as **HOME** and variable value as **%userprofile%** to set the home dir in windows.By default your .ssh folder should be there.

```
To view or change environment variables:
 1.Right-click My Computer, and then click Properties.
 2. Click the Advanced tab.
 3. Click Environment variables.
 4. Click one the following options, for either a user or a system variable:
   o    Click New to add a new variable name and value.
   o    Click an existing variable, and then click Edit to change its name orvalue.
   o    Click an existing variable, and then click Delete to remove it.
```

[Complete article to set up environment variable](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519)